# Where condition in Mondrian

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

**MDX query to find the employee salary more then 5000**

```
select 
    {
      [Measures].[Total Employee],
      [Measures].[Total Salary]
    } on columns,
NON EMPTY 
    {
     (
      [Department].[All Department],
      [Position].[All Position],
      [Employee].[All Employee])
    } on rows
from Salary
where 
      [Measures].[Total Salary]>5000
```

**My schema**

```html
<Schema name="Foodmart">
  <Cube name="Salary" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="employee" alias="">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="department_id" name="Department">
      <Hierarchy name="All Department" visible="true" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All Department" primaryKey="department_id" primaryKeyTable="department">
        <Table name="department">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Dept" visible="true" column="department_description" uniqueMembers="true">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="position_id" name="Position">
      <Hierarchy name="All Position" visible="false" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All Position" primaryKey="position_id" primaryKeyTable="position">
        <Table name="position">
        </Table>
        <Level name="position" visible="true" table="position" column="position_title" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" name="Employee">
      <Hierarchy name="All Employee" visible="true" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All Employee">
        <Table name="employee" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="New Level 0" visible="true" column="full_name" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="Total Salary" column="salary" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
    <Measure name="Total Employee" column="employee_id" aggregator="distinct-count" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Comment: Please Help anyone......

Comment: Even if sub-select(what you call subquery) doesn't work in Mondrian, you have got 2 perfectly valid solutions. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know if you're coming from `slq` it looks ok but the following is wrong:

```
WHERE
      [Measures].[Total Salary]>5000
```

You could use the filter function inside the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
    {
      [Measures].[Total Employee],
      [Measures].[Total Salary]
    } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
    {
     (
      [Department].[All Department],
      [Position].[All Position]
     )
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Salary]
WHERE FILTER(
        [Employee].[All Employee].CHILDREN,
        [Measures].[Total Salary]>5000
      );
```

The above will be filtering employees whose total salary for all time is greater than 5000.

The filter could go around the complete cross set if you like the following but you'll get a list of all the respective employees returned:

```
SELECT
    {
      [Measures].[Total Employee],
      [Measures].[Total Salary]
    } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
    FILTER(
     {
      (
       [Department].[All Department],
       [Position].[All Position],
       [Employee].[All Employee].CHILDREN
      )
     }
    ,[Measures].[Total Salary]>5000
   ) ON ROWS
FROM [Salary];
```

Or use a `HAVING` clause across the whole set - although this is logically different that the above:

```
SELECT
    {
      [Measures].[Total Employee],
      [Measures].[Total Salary]
    } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
       [Department].[All Department]
     * [Position].[All Position],
     * [Employee].[All Employee].CHILDREN
   HAVING [Measures].[Total Salary]>5000 ON ROWS
FROM [Salary];
```

---

Edit

You can move the filter to a sub-cube if you still require the [All EmplyeeS] member on ROWS:

```
SELECT
    {
      [Measures].[Total Employee],
      [Measures].[Total Salary]
    } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
      [Department].[All Department]
     *[Position].[All Position]
     *[Employee].[All Employee]
    ON ROWS
FROM 
(
SELECT
    FILTER(
        [Employee].[All Employee].CHILDREN,
        [Measures].[Total Salary]>5000
      ) ON 0
FROM [Salary] 
);
```

Comment: Mondrian Error:More than one function matches signature '<Member>.MEMBERS'; they are: <Hierarchy>.Members, <Level>.Members
Following error occured while executing 1 and 2 query Please help me?

Comment: @devendrasingh I'll edit my scripts as I've slightly misinterpreted your requirements

Comment: thanks @whytheq.
But it is not displaying total employee on the rows.
First query

Comment: and taking a lot time to load the result.

Comment: @devendrasingh try adding the total employee member to the rows? It should throw an error - this is because we're already using it in the `WHERE` clause. There are ways around this - I will add an edit.

Comment: Filter is iterative and therefore to be avoided. Alternative to speed this up should be a seperate question.

Comment: ok @whytheq. while expending all department it is throwing error.

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   :error

Comment: 1,155 total employee in employee hierarchy

Comment: @devendrasingh am I interpreting your code ok - is this a member or a level? `[Department].[All Department]`. When you do this cross join are you expecting 1 row? `[Department].[All Department] * [Position].[All Position] * [Employee].[All Employee]`

Comment: --@whytheq --thanks for your time. I think we are quite near to the solution.
 but sill showing---- "Syntax error at line 12, column 1, token '(' "----- . 
I search this in google but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: i think ------unfortunately I am using Mondrian and it doesn't support subquery :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running into space/memory issues. If so, can you try the code below:

```
select 
    {
      [Measures].[Total Employee],
      [Measures].[Total Salary]
    } on columns,
NON EMPTY 
    {
     NonEmpty(
              (
               [Department].[All Department] *
               [Position].[All Position] *
               [Employee].[All Employee]
              )
              ,[Measures].[Total Salary]
             )
    } having [Measures].[Total Salary] > 5000 on rows
from Salary
```

The `NonEmpty` function will remove the empty tuples while cross join.

**EDIT 1**
How about now?

```
with member [Measures].SalGrtrThan5000 
as
IIF
  (
   [Measures].[Total Salary] > 5000, 
   1, 
   NULL
  )

select 
    {
      [Measures].[Total Employee],
      [Measures].[Total Salary]
    } on columns,
NON EMPTY 
    {
     NonEmpty(
              (
               [Department].[All Department] *
               [Position].[All Position] *
               [Employee].[All Employee]
              )
              ,[Measures].SalGrtrThan5000 
             )
    } 
      on rows
from Salary
```

**EDIT, using EXISTS**

```
select 
    {
      [Measures].[Total Employee],
      [Measures].[Total Salary]
    } on columns,
NON EMPTY 
    {
     FILTER
        (
            EXISTS (
                      (
                       [Department].[All Department] *
                       [Position].[All Position] *
                       [Employee].[All Employee]
                      )
              , , "SomeMeasureGroup"
                   ) //EXISTS will remove non-empty tuples this way
        , [Measures].[Total Salary] > 5000
        )//Filters the set
    } 
      on rows
from Salary
```

Replace "SomeMeasureGroup" with the actual name of measure group to which `[Measures].[Total Salary]` belongs. There is a cell-by-cell filter but with the use of `EXISTS`, hopefully it will be faster this time.

Comment: Thnaks @Sourav . But still showing ---Mondrian Error:Syntax error at line 16, column 7, token 'having'

Comment: we cant use ""members"" with the Hierarchy  [All Department],[All Position],[All Employee] -----showing  Mondrian Error:More than one function matches signature '<Member>.members'; they are: <Hierarchy>.Members, <Level>.Members------

Comment: ok, then remove `members` and try. `.members` works fine with ssas. I haven't worked on Mondrian before.

Comment: Now showing this-----Mondrian Error:No function matches signature 'NonEmpty(<Numeric Expression>, <Member>)'-----

Comment: There is no `NonEmpty` in Mondrian! Thank god I don't work in Mondrian!! ;)

Comment: Ok I did some research and found that `EXISTS` function exists in Mondrian. Try the edited code. Also, there is no `NonEmpty` function in Mondrian. The common substitute is `FILTER` with `IsEmpty`