# How to aggregate multiple hierarchies of a single dimension using Mondrian?

Tags: java, olap, mondrian

I have the following MDX query :

```
SELECT {[MEASURES].[MEASURE_VALUE]} ON COLUMNS,
     {
        {[DIMENSION_A].[HIERARCHY_1]},
        {[DIMENSION_A].[HIERARCHY_2]}
    }
       ON ROWS
FROM [MY_CUBE]
```

As expected I get 2 values, one for each hierarchy.

**Question :** I want to have a single value representing the sum of the 2 values I got from the query above. I cannot figure out how to do that, I tried the following

```
SELECT {[MEASURES].[MEASURE_VALUE]} ON COLUMNS,
     {
        {[DIMENSION_A].[HIERARCHY_1] * [DIMENSION_A].[HIERARCHY_2]}
    }
       ON ROWS
FROM [MY_CUBE]
```

but I got this error : 
`Caused by: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Tuple contains more than one member of hierarchy '[DIMENSION_A.HIERARCHY_2]'.`

I'm not too familiar with Mondrian and by reading the documentation it seems like you can only crossjoin different dimensions and not hierarchies of the same dimension. In an SQL fashion and given a very simple context I believe it would be the equivalent of a `WHERE` clause such as :

```
WHERE DIMENSION_A.HIERARCHY = HIERARCHY_1 OR DIMENSION_A.HIERARCHY = HIERARCHY_2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .where clause for it. please refer to the below url for details:
[Where condition in Mondrian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110971/where-condition-in-mondrian)